# Code is requesting the yahoo weather service again and again

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, yahoo-weather-api

I have developed an android app which uses `Yahoo! Weather API`  for getting weather information, as `Yahoo! Weather API` allows to request the service only `10 to 20` times per hour. my app has tow activities when I switch back and forth between them my app requests the weather service again and again my code for this is :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    String nameOfCity= pref.getString("cityname", cityNameInput.getText().toString());      
    getWeather(null, nameOfCity);// this the AsyncTask which is used to request Yahoo! Weather service.
    cityNameInput.setText(nameOfCity);
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("My_TAG", "in onResume()");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    editor = pref.edit();
    if(cityNameInput.getText().toString().equals("")){
        cityNameInput.setText(yahooWeatherInfo.getLocationCity());
    }else{
        editor.putString("cityname", cityNameInput.getText().toString());
    }
    editor.commit();
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("MY_TAG", "in onPause()");
}
```

Now please tell me how to restrict that not to request the `Yahoo! Weather Service` again and again on switching between activities.

Comment: Look into making your data request an Android Service.

Comment: @MorrisonChang how can I do that please give me some hint if ?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at you code.

You are calling `getWeather(null, nameOfCity);` in `onResume()`. This `onResume()` method is called when your activity resume once again.

For ex: A ---> B then Press back from B activity then A activity `onResume()` method will be called and its makes request to server. So call this method `` `getWeather(null, nameOfCity); `` in `onCreate(bundle)`. which is called only once when activity is created.

Comment: Friend first thanks for your precious consideration to my problem, I have tried according to your suggestion to the `getWeather(null, nameOfCity);` in `OnCreate()` but still app is requesting again and again to server.

Comment: yes I have removed `getWeather(null, nameOfCity);` from `onResume()` .. but still same problem!

Comment: @ArshadAliArshay You need to debug the application some where in your code bug that continue making server call.